Python 3.10 cannot open shared object file librdkafka
I am trying to upgrade a relatively simple Python app thats reads a Kafka Topic, processes and then calls the API.
Currently it is running in a docker container based on Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I am looking to upgrade to Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
The docker container builds without issues but there is an issue when running the app or the tests.
ImportError while importing test module '/code/fr24/tests/test_feed.py'.

Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.

Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
...
...
from confluent_kafka.cimpl import Consumer as _ConsumerImpl
E   ImportError: librdkafka.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I added
RUN apt-get install -y librdkafka-dev
to the Ubuntu 22.04 Dockerfile. Then I got a different error
ImportError: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Which makes me think it's likely a path issue.
docker-compose run fr24 python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"
returns
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/_pdbpp_path_hack
/code/fr24
/code
/usr/lib/python310.zip
/usr/lib/python3.10
/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

docker-compose run fr24 env returns among others
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PYTHONPATH=/code/fr24:

am I missing something simple here?

Run: dpkg -L librdkafka-dev | grep librdkafka.so.  My install is in in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.  I had no issue installing confluent-kafka via pip and then importing.

When you installed this, how did you get the dynamic library? Did it come automatically with pip install?

Have you tried to use this image base: https://hub.docker.com/r/ubuntu/kafka? It seems to be also based on Ubuntu 22.04.

The issue was the version of confluent-kafka being installed from pypi. It was picking up the version packaged for musl C and not gcc.
Once I forced the correct confluent-kafka package to be installed and included
RUN apt-get install -y librdkafka-dev
on the Dockerfile everything worked.
